Question about a Plex setup that I am planning?
I have no experience of Ubuntu so please go easy on me.
I am planning to set up a Windows 11 virtual machine within host Ubuntu. The Windows machine will have a pool of drives (using NTFS system) which will have all my media collection. I would then like the host Ubuntu to have full access to this pool and use it to run plex on Ubuntu. Is it possible?
Thanks!

Sure it's possible. But since Windows must be running anyway for the VM to be active, and since Plex is available for Windows, and since NTFS is Windows-native, why bother with the VM at all?

The NTFS drives will need to be in a clean state.. ie. you won't be able to use them in windows then use hibernate to pause windows operation (and do note that windows fastboot is a form of hibernate that leaves drives in an unclean state*)

@user535733
The reason is that I have read that Linux works better when it comes to things like Transcoding and HDR tone mapping.

@guiverc
I plan to use a 2TB NVME solely for the OS. My data drives will be separate. These data drives included drives of varying capacities and are about 30-35 drives. That is why I need to make a pool to present it to Plex.

Are you using the Windows VM and NTFS just for the drive pool? You can do that with Linux too, you know...

@sotirov
I guess you are talking about mergerfs. I did try that but as I have never worked with Linux, I was not able to set it up. I tried 2 hard drives and I could only create a pool with a single one!

@drsa there are so many different ways to have drive pools in Ubuntu. Depending on what you need, zfs may be a good solution for what you.

@sotirov I just need to make a pool of drives of various capacities where I can easily add or remove a drive. I do not want any raid capabilities, just a simple pool.
